# Limitação de 6 Requisição seguidas no ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, nodemon

Ola, estou fazendo um aplicação em que efetuo uma requisição ajax para fazer um cadastro no banco, a requisição está funcionando sem problemas. Porém notei que só aceita até 6 requisições seguidas sem atualizar a pagina após isto o servidor bloqueia. Estou utilizando o servidor do nodemon rodando no gulp.js

Gostaria de saber se isto é um limitação padrão do ajax ou do navegador ?

É possivel parametrizar para aumentar o numero de requisição seguidas ou diminuir ?

Aqui está a requisição ajax

```
    $('#form-aluno').submit(() => {
    let data = $('#form-aluno').serialize();
    console.log(data);

    const register = $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "/alunos/register/save",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data
    })

    register.done((resposta) => {
        console.log(resposta)
    })


    return false;
})
```

Controller que grava os dados /alunos/register/save

```
    module.exports = () => {
    return {
        register: (req, res) => {
            data = {
                name: req.body.name,
                age: req.body.age,
                obs: req.body.age,
                turma: parseInt(req.body.turma_id)

            }

            console.log(data)

            Aluno.create({
                AL_NAME: data.name,
                AL_IDADE: data.age,
                AL_OBS: data.obs,
                AL_TURMA: data.turma
            })


            res.status(201)



        }
    }
}
```

**OBS: A Aplicação está funcionando gostaria apenas de saber sobre está limitação de requisição para fins de curiosidade e futuros projetos**